# PHP-SOAP extension loading error

Tags: php, apache, soap, soap-client

I am trying to install Opencats.For that it is required to enable soap.I have enabled Soap.

```
soap
Soap Client => enabled
Soap Server => enabled
soap.wsdl_cache => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir => /tmp => /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled => 1 => 1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit => 5 => 5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl => 86400 => 86400
```

But while installation Still it shows

```
PHP SOAP extension (soap) is not loaded.
Check your settings in php.ini.

CATS Open Source will function without SOAP, but CATS Professional functionality will not be supported.

Under certain Linux / BSD distributions, the PHP SOAP extension is a separate package.

Ubuntu: Run "apt-get install php-soap" and restart your webserver.

Debian: Run "apt-get install php5-soap" and restart your webserver.

FreeBSD: Install the php5-soap port, or configure SOAP support in the php-extensions port and restart your webserver.
```

I am using fedora 17 os.
Php :PHP 5.4.17

php.ini

```
[soap]
; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-enabled
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1

; Sets the directory name where SOAP extension will put cache files.
; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-dir
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"

; (time to live) Sets the number of second while cached file will be used
; instead of original one.
; http://php.net/soap.wsdl-cache-ttl
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400

; Sets the size of the cache limit. (Max. number of WSDL files to cache)
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
```

Everything which is required i did. But still problem is not solved.

Comment: Did you tried phpinfo(). May be you have different php configs for cli and web server?

Comment: yes i have checked.its enabled only

Comment: try to add extension=soap.so into [soap] section, may be it will help.

Comment: Yes i included  extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/soap.so
still same problem